# Error "okhttp3.responsebody$Companion$asresponseBody$1@8d63711d"

Tags: android, api, kotlin, chatgpt-api

I am currently developing an app that uses the ChatGPT OpenAI API to provide conversational AI capabilities.

Whenever I try to send a message, the bot sends this error
"okhttp3.responsebody$Companion$asresponsebody$1@8d63711d."

Could someone please tell me how to solve this error?

Here is my code:

```
class ChatviewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _messageList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Message>>()
    val messageList: LiveData<MutableList<Message>> get() = _messageList

    init {
        _messageList.value = mutableListOf()
    }

    fun addToChat(message: String, sentBy: String, timeStamp: String) {
        val currentList = _messageList.value ?: mutableListOf()
        currentList.add(Message(message, sentBy, timeStamp))
        _messageList.postValue(currentList)
    }

    fun getCurrentTimestamp() : String{
        return SimpleDateFormat("hh mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    }

    private fun addResponse(response: String) {
        _messageList.value?.removeAt(_messageList.value?.size?.minus(1) ?: 0)
        addToChat(response, Message.SENT_BY_BOT, getCurrentTimestamp())
    }

    private suspend fun handleApiResponse(response :
                                          Response<CompletionResponse>){
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                response.body()?.let {
                    completionResponse ->
                    val result = completionResponse.choices.firstOrNull()?.text
                    if (result != null){
                        addResponse(result.trim())
                    }else{
                        addResponse("No Choices found")
                    }
                }
            }else{
                addResponse("Failed to get response ${response.errorBody()}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun callApi(question: String) {
        addToChat("Typing....", Message.SENT_BY_BOT, getCurrentTimestamp())

        val completionRequest = OnCompletion(
            model = "text-davinci-003",
            prompt = question,
            maxToken = 4000
        )
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = ApiClientClass.apiService.getCompletions(completionRequest)
                handleApiResponse(response)
            } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                addResponse("Timeout :  $e")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
interface OpenAi {
    // https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
    @Headers("Authorization:Bearer$MY_API_KEY")
    @POST("v1/completions")
    suspend fun getCompletions(@Body completionResponse : OnCompletion)
    : Response<CompletionResponse>
}
```